# No module named psycopg2 even after i installed psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2, psycopg

I have

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import psycopg2
```

in my first couple lines of the code. 
However, it shows that

```
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
```

even after I install psycopg2

Below is the detail errors from the ternimal.

```
 432p1:/vagrant> pip3 install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.7.3.1-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.6MB 526kB/s 
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
Successfully installed psycopg2-2.6.1
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
432p1:/vagrant> ./test-example.py pys.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test-example.py", line 2, in <module>
    import psycopg2
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
432p1:/vagrant> ./clean-example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./clean-example.py", line 2, in <module>
    import psycopg2
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
432p1:/vagrant>
```

In addition i tried to run import in my python console and there is no error, however,when i run the test it has error

```
432p1:/vagrant> python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Aug 18 2017, 17:48:00) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
>>> ./test-example.py pys.py 
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ./test-example.py pys.py 
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Thanks

Comment: what is your default python version ?

Comment: likely that the location where psycopg2 is installed (by pip3) is different from the location where python3's packages are located.
you would need to resolve the two - personally resolved this by using the correct path for my environment's pip3 (e.g. /User/vidyut/anaconda2/envs/py36/bin/pip install psycopg2)

Answer (score 0):

Check if it was actually installed where you expected it to be -- you can compare other packages that have been imported successfully. Run `pip show psycopg2` vs `pip show pandas` or some other package and compare if they're in the right place.

In my case, only the psycopg2 dist files had been installed in that directory for some reason, and so I uninstalled and reinstalled and it worked.